# If value exists in environment

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Is there a way how to check if value exists in R environment and if == TRUE, assign this existing value otherwise assign something else?

In other words, I have nothing in my R right now and I created this if else statement.

```
test <- if_else(exists("my_value"), my_value, "my value missing, assigning this string")
```

Result of

```
 exists("my_value")
```

is:

```
exists("my_value")
[1] FALSE
```

But once I run whole code I get this

> Error in if_else(exists("my_value"), my_value, "my value missing, assigning this string") : 
>         object 'my_value' not found

Comment: Try doing `ls()`. It will show you all objects you have defined in your global env.

Comment: If you use `ifelse` instead of `if_else` it should work.

Comment: if `my_value` does not exist, after your statement, `test` will exist but `my_value` still won't

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate, since the problem here is that OP is misusing `if_else`

Comment: @HongOoi true, I reopened, though title is misleading imo. also, as `if_else` is not base R, tag of corresponding package should be included....

Comment: I guess the question is "how do I do this with `dplyr::if_else`?"

Comment: @zx8754 The answer should be "use `if() ... else ...`", since that is the control flow statement, not ifelse or if_else.

Comment: @HongOoi Yes, agree, I was just composing the answer. Internet failed on me... so a bit of a delay.

Answer (score 3):

*if() {} else {}* is more suitable for this case:

```
if(exists("my_value")){ 
  test <- my_value } else { 
    test <- "my value missing, assigning this string"}
```

Using `dplyr::if_else(condition, true, false, missing = NULL)` won't work as it is checking the values for **true** and **false** are of the same length, class, type, hence the error.

I am guessing it could be done with `if_else`, if we manage to make values for true and false of the same class somehow.